# guaribar ou garibar?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia

Estou acostumado a ouvir, aqui no centro-oeste paulista, a palavra "guaribar", também "dar uma guaribada", querendo dizer "fazer uma arrumação" ou "limpeza", ou "dar um retoque".

E eis que [leio](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8319/qual-o-motivo-fechamento-para-quando-o-usu%C3%A1rio-s%C3%B3-quer-uma-garibada-no-c%C3%B3digo) "garibada".

Em uma pesquisa breve...

[Daqui](https://origemdapalavra.com.br/palavras/guaribar/):

> O certo seria guaribada. A origem seria o apelido de um indivíduo em São Paulo que se destacava por tornar apresentáveis os carros que lhe eram dados para vender, e que atendia pelo apelido de Guariba, do Tupi GWA’RIWA, o nome dado aos bugios por eles. Mas não podemos garantir este étimo.

Já [daqui](http://glbrito.blogspot.com/2006/11/curiosidades-da-lngua-portuguesa.html?m=1):

> A palavra gari provém de um nome próprio. Aleixo Gary foi o primeiro proprietário de empresa de serviços de limpeza do Rio de Janeiro, no final do século passado. Seus funcionários eram inicialmente chamados pela população de empregados do Gary; posteriormente, apenas garis, aplicada, assim, mais uma vez, a lei do menor esforço, lei de que o povo tanto gosta, desde os tempos do latim vulgar.
> Daí surgiu o verbo garibar (limpar) e o substantivo garibada, que muitos usam de forma equivocada: guaribar, guaribada. Influência de Guariba, cidade paulista famosa pelo número de bóias-frias? É certo que não.
>
> Fonte: Revista Gafite - vol. 3 número 4
> Outubro/Novembro de 1989
> Autor: Luiz Antonio Sacconi

"Gari" é termo comum aqui para funcionário responsável por varrer as vias públicas.

Enfim, qual a origem mais aceita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### O que dizem os dicionários

***Guaribar*** e ***guaribada*** é o que eu encontro nos dicionários, como se pode ver no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/guaribar), no [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/guaribar/),  ou no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), que eu cito aqui, desenvolvendo algumas das abreviações:

> **guaribada** *s.f. Brasil RJ SP informal* ato ou efeito de guaribar ʘ ETIM provavelmente feminino substantivado de *guaribado*, particípio de *guaribar*
>
> **guaribar** *v.* (*depois de* 1950) *Brasil RJ SP informal* **1** *t.d.* AUTOM preparar um carro para que desenvolva maior velocidade que os outros da sua série; envenenar **2** *t.d.* AUTOM preparar o motor e/ou carroçaria de um carro em mau estado de modo a enganar um comprador **3** *t.d. por extensão* ajeitar, arrumar ou acomodar de maneira apressada e superficial ʘ ETIM segundo Dicionário da Gíria Brasileira  *sub voce gatilho*, antropónimo *Guariba* (paulista especializado em transformar calhambeques em belos automóveis) + *ar*

### Primeiras ocorrências

Agora, *garibar* e *garibada* também se encontra, mas raramente, pelos menos nos primeiros tempos na imprensa. Eu vasculhei a [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx), que tem o texto integral de centenas de periódicos dos últimos dois séculos, e eis os resultados:

**Número de artigos e anúncios em que a palavra aparece na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx)**

```
Década       Garibada   Guaribada           Garibar   Guaribar
1950-59        1 (5)     7* (50)               0        2 (20)
1960-69        0         2                     0        6 (7)
1970-79        1        27 (32)                1        4
1980-89**      6        62                     1        8
Notas: entre parênteses, total incluindo repetições; cada anúncio aparece em vários dias
       * Sete anúncios pouco variando entre si.
       ** Não vi cada um dos artigos, não sei se há repetições.
```

Os exemplos dos anos 50 são todos de anúncios na imprensa carioca, mas denunciando origem paulista. Aparecem quase todos em 1953 e 1954. Eis o primeiro:

> **GUARIBADA — PAULISTA**
> R, Gal. Roca, 410-A. Junto à Praça Saenz Pena
> Surgiu no Rio de Janeiro o que faltava para limpeza do seu automóvel.
> Em 24 horas V. S. terá o carro usado, completamente novo
> Polimento geral — limpeza de estofamento — Metais e motor com retoques de pintura. A máxima perfeição e rapidez.
> [Jornal do Brasil, Rio de Janeiro, 17-9-1953](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_07&pesq=guaribada&pasta=ano%20195)

Em 1954 aparecem anúncios muito parecidos oferecendo a “Guaribada Paulista” em outras duas oficinas no Rio de Janeiro: [Garagem Dique](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_07&pesq=%22Guaribada%20Paulista%20Garagem%20Dique%22&pasta=ano%20195) a partir de abril, [Garagem Batista](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_07&pesq=%22Guaribada%20Paulista%20constando%22&pasta=ano%20195) a partir de agosto. Terá sido uma espécie de franchising?

Em janeiro de 1954 vemos o que parece ser uma concorrente — a “Bandeirante”.  Séries de anúncios oferecem, sempre na mesma garagem, primeiro uma “Guariba Bandeirante” (a palavra *guaribada* aparece também no texto, [Jornal do Brasil, 12-1-1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_07&pesq=%22guaribada%20desaparecem%22&pasta=ano%20195)), depois uma “Guaribada Bandeirante” ([Jornal do Brasil, 15-1-1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_07&pesq=%22Guaribada%20Bandeirante%22&pasta=ano%20195) e [Jornal dos Sports, 21-1-1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=112518_02&pesq=guaribada&pasta=ano%20195)), e depois uma “Gariba Badeirante”, que inclui *garibada* no texto ([Jornal dos Sports, RJ, 7-2-1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=112518_02&pesq=garibada&pasta=ano%20195)); depois um série de 18 anúncios convida a *guaribar* o carro na mesma garagem, sem mencionar nem *guaribada* nem *garibada* [(Jornal do Brasil, 26-4-1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_07&pesq=guaribar&pasta=ano%20195)).

Foi já nos anos 70 que encontrei *guaribada* noutras coisas que não automóveis: como “uma guaribada na estrutura musical” da Rádio Guanabara ([Correio da Manhã, RJ, 1971](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=089842_08&pesq=guaribada&pasta=ano%20197)) ou “uma guaribada violenta na praça” dos Cadetes ([Jornal do Brasil, RJ, 1976](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_09&pesq=%22guaribada%20violenta%22&pasta=ano%20197)).

Como se pode ver por estes exemplos, ao contrário do que sugerem os dicionários, pelo menos nos primeiros tempos, a guaribada não tinha de ser superficial, e uma guaribada no automóvel não era necessariamente para iludir comprador.

### Em busca do Sr. Guariba

Encontrei dois artigos dos anos 60 que atribuem a origem dos termos ao tal Guariba. No primeiro ([Diário de Notícias, 1966](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=093718_04&pesq=guaribar&pasta=ano%20196)), o jornalista Nestor de Holanda conta que o seu amigo Telmo de Oliveira conheceu o “cidadão Guariba” por volta de 1950. O Guariba

> possuía pequenas instalações em S. Paulo, no Bairro dos Campos Elísios, nas imediações da Rua Conselheiro Neves, [onde se dedicava ao] trabalho de reparo na apresentação dos autos que vinham do interior, tanto para que se apresentassem bem na capital, como para que fôssem [sic] vendidos por melhores preços. Sua profissão era pôr em ordem, brilhando como novas, tôda a carroçaria e tôda a equipagem. O negócio passou a render, Guariba criou reputação profissional, popularizou-se, contratou auxiliares, progrediu.
> [Nestor de Holanda, “Telhados de Vidro — Guariba”, Diário de Notícias, Rio de Janeiro, 29-6-1966](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=093718_04&pesq=guaribar&pasta=ano%20196)

O amigo Telmo de Oliveira contou ainda ao jornalista que na altura, 1966, Guariba já era “o dr. Guariba, da alta sociedade paulistana”, mas não nos dá nem mais nomes nem pormenores.

Outro artigo, de 1969 ([Realidade, São Paulo, 1969](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=213659&pesq=guaribar&pasta=ano%20196)) dá-nos uma pista mais concreta, Adalberto Camargo, órfão que subiu a pulso, enriqueceu e foi em 1967 eleito deputado federal por São Paulo. Segundo o artigo, Camargo não é o Guariba mas teve uma sociedade com ele. Tendo trabalhado como vendedor de carros usados, Camargo:

> Em 1951 pensa numa loja própria, mas percebe que só alguma coisas de especial atrairia os fregueses. Lembra-se do Guariba, o baliza do cordão carnavalesco Vai-Vai. O homem era um artista para limpar, polir e enfeitar um carro usado. Os vendedores viviam a assediá-lo, mas êle não tinha local fixo de trabalho. Seu “instituto de beleza” funcionava embaixo das árvores, sem qualquer segurança ou constância.
> Camargo propõe a Guariba montar uma oficina para êle, pagando tôdas as despesas e sem tirar rendimento. Guariba aceita e aparece um anúncio nos jornais:
> “Dê uma *guaribada* no seu carro e o veja tão bonito como um nôvo. Loja e oficina Marquês de Itu, de Adalberto Camargo.”
> [“Adalberto, pioneiro no aluguel de carros”, Realidade, São Paulo, setembro de 1969](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=213659&pesq=guaribar&pasta=ano%20196)

Claramente, *guaribar* e *guaribada* são as palavras aceites nos dicionários, e, se não foram as originais, pelo menos foram de longe as mais comuns na imprensa de 1950 a 1990. E se a história da origem no tal Guariba não é verdadeira, então está pelo menos muito bem contada.

### Então e o *gari* ’varredor de ruas’?

A origem de *gari* ’varredor de ruas’ está muito bem documentada. Começo com o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002):

> **gari** *s.2g.* (1909 Careta n.º 36 06/02) *B* m.q. *VARREDOR DE RUA* ʘ ETIM antr. Aleixo *Gary*, incorporador da empresa a cujo cargo esteve o serviço de público de limpeza das ruas, no Rio de Janeiro; f.hist. 1909 *gary*

A [Companhia Municipal de Limpeza Urbana](https://www.rio.rj.gov.br/web/comlurb/exibeconteudo?id=2815129) do Rio de Janeiro, conta a história da sua origem num contrato celebrado em 1876 com Aleixo Gary, contrato esse noticiado na [Gazeta de Noticias (RJ, 11-10-1876)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=103730_01&pesq=%22Aleixo%20Gary%20pelo%20praso%22&pasta=ano%20187). E a primeira ocorrência de *gari* enquanto ’varredor de ruas’ que o Houaiss indica é na revista [Careta (RJ, 6 de fevereiro de 1909)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=083712&pesq=gary&pasta=ano%20190). Trata-se de conselhos, “Os doze nãos da boa creada”, e um deles é “Não namore o gary nem o padeiro”. Uma [Careta de 7 de janeiro de 1911](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=083712&pesq=gary&pasta=ano%20191) é mais clara acerca do que é um gary: “Um gary da limpeza publica, estando a capinar uma rua de Botafogo […]”. *Gary* era um nome estrageiro, mas na altura usava-se ainda o y em português também (como em *abysmo* ou *hypothese*).

Agora, foi este *gari* que originou *guaribada* através de *garibada*? Os dicionários não é isso que dizem. E além de toda a evidência apontando a origem de *guaribada* em São Paulo, no ramo automóvel, e no tal Guariba, uma origem de *garibada* em *gari* é intrinsecamente improvável. Semanticamente, passar de ’varredor de ruas’ para ’embelezador de automóveis’ ainda vá que não vá. O grande problema é fonético. Para não sermos influenciados, se quiséssemos um verbo com o significado ’fazer como o tupi’, formaríamos *tubibar*? Ou ’fazer como a Lili’ seria *lilibar*? Creio que não. De *gari* o que esperaríamos seria *garar* /*gariar* /*garear*, tal como (links ao Aulete) *judeu* → [*judiar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/judiar), *cigano* → [*ciganar*/*ciganear*](http://www.aulete.com.br/ciganear), *pirata* → [*piratear*](http://www.aulete.com.br/piratear) ou *vagabundo* → [*vagabundar*/*vagabundear;*](http://www.aulete.com.br/vagabundar) ou *garejar*, como *mouro* → [*mourejar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/mourejar), ou talvez ainda *garizar*, como (conto do) *vigário* → [*virgarizar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/vigarizar). Mas verbos formados com a adição de um sufixo *-bar*, eu não conheço.

A formação de *garibar* a partir de *gari* seria mais provável se houvesse uma influência externa que fornecesse o b. O que me sugere a hipótese de *garibar* ter surgido como variante de *guaribar* influenciada por *gari*. Mas também poderia muito bem ser alguém que não ouviu bem ou não se lembrou bem e simplificou para *garibar*; a associação a *gari* poderia vir mais tarde. Qualquer destas hipóteses pressupõe naturalmente que *guaribar* é o verbo original, como parece ser.